# umbraco macro XSLT not working

Tags: xslt, umbraco

I get an image folder parameter (folder present in the media section) from macro in Umbraco and then loop  through the all the images. First thing I check that folder is not empty and then during the loop I further try to check if an image name is equal to "marhall_spadayhpbanner_jul131%20(4).jpg" then I need to put a different link to anchor. I have tried the following xslt code but for some reason its not working as expected and the second condition (when image equal to 'media/42595/marhall_spadayhpbanner_jul131%20(4).jpg' ) is never true.

Any ideas thanks

```
<xsl:for-each select="$imageFolderContents/node [@nodeTypeAlias='Image']">
    <xsl:if test="string(current()/data [@alias='umbracoFile']) != ''">
        <a href="www.somelink.com">
            <img alt="{current()/@nodeName}">
                <xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="current()/data [@alias='umbracoFile']"/></xsl:attribute>
            </img>
        </a>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="string(current()/data [@alias='umbracoFile']) = 'media/42595/marhall_spadayhpbanner_jul131%20(4).jpg'">
        <a href="someotherlink.com">
            <img alt="{current()/@nodeName}">
                <xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="current()/data [@alias='umbracoFile']"/></xsl:attribute>
            </img>
        </a>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The output is the code is

```
<div style="clear: both; position: relative; height: auto;" class="slideshow innerfade"><a href="http://gifts.skchase.com/marhall/summerspa/" style="z-index: 5; position: absolute; display: none;"><img alt="dont be a fool" src="/media/42595/marhall_spadayhpbanner_jul131 (4).jpg"></a><a href="https://gifts.skchase.com/marhall/summerspa/" style="z-index: 4; position: absolute; display: block;"><img alt="dont be a fool" src="/media/42595/marhall_spadayhpbanner_jul131 (4).jpg"></a><a href="http://gifts.skchase.com/marhall/summerspa/" style="z-index: 3; position: absolute; display: none;"><img alt="MH-Ext-16-hero.jpg" src="/media/1548/MH-Ext-16-hero.jpg"></a><a href="http://gifts.skchase.com/marhall/summerspa/" style="z-index: 2; position: absolute; display: none;"><img alt="golf_hero_arial_new.jpg" src="/media/1816/golf_hero_arial_new.jpg"></a><a href="http://gifts.skchase.com/marhall/summerspa/" style="z-index: 1; position: absolute; display: none;"><img alt="MH-Spa-e-25-hero.jpg" src="/media/1552/MH-Spa-e-25-hero.jpg"></a></div>
```

Comment: I suspect the `%20` might have something to do with this, but without seeing your input XML nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: I don't have the xml to share unfortunately but the following is the output of this xslt code

Comment: What do you mean, you don't have the input XML? Remove any detail you don't want to share and then share it. Anyway, here's a hint: There is no `%20` in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the %20 in your if statement to a space. That should fix it.